# How to use PFQuery for array of PFObject stored as values of NSDictionary

Tags: ios, nsdictionary, parse-platform

I'm using parse.com in an iOS app to store data to the parse cloud service.  I'm having trouble with a query of nested objects.  I have the following data model:

Class "Game"
contains "winners"

"winners" is an array of `NSDictionary`, each item in the dictionary is a mapping of 1 Player to N Powers

playerPowers value is an **array of PFObjects** (powers only have a name currently) for **key:objectId** of a player (PFObject)

For each winner, I add to "winners" (there can be multiple winners) an `NSDictionary` object, like so:

```
NSDictionary * winnerWithPowers = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:tempPowers
                                                forKey:[aWinnerPFObject objectId]];
[newGame addObject:winnerWithPowers forKey:@"winners"];
```

For each item in the dictionary, the key is an existing objectId of a player and the value is an array of `PFObjects` (powers) also on the server.  When i query for the "winners" i'd like to retrieve **all** the data populated, all winners and their respective power `PFObjects` with all their data.  When i query for the "winners" the details of each power `PFObject` is incomplete (value for key:name is null).  following is the query, then the code that prints results, followed by output of a dictionary containing two winners:

// In **viewWillAppear:**

```
PFQuery * gamesQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Game"];
[gamesQuery orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
[gamesQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray * theGames, NSError * error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR: There was an error with the Query for Games!");
    } else {
        _gamesPF = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:theGames];
        [_tableView reloadData];
    }
}];
```

// in the tableview **cellForRowAtIndexPath:** method (it's my own TableViewController)

```
NSArray * testArray = [[_gamesPF objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"winners"];
if ([testArray count] > 0) {
    // print contents of first dictionary winners entry
    NSLog(@"TestDictfromPF %@", [testArray objectAtIndex:0]);
}
```

Log:

```
2013-01-18 09:42:26.430 GamesTourney[20972:19d03] TestDictfromPF {

jchtlqsuIY =     (
    "<Power:OlJfby1iuz:(null)> {\n}",  // problem is {\n}. Data exists on server but not in local structure after query
    "<Power:eQkMUThGOh:(null)> {\n}"   // ditto
);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you retrieve a `PFObject` (Game) that is related to other PFObjects (an array of Powers), the value of those Powers are not retrieved. You will have to fetch all the values of those Powers in subsequent fetch requests.

From the Parse documentation:

> By default, when fetching an object, related PFObjects are not
>   fetched. These objects' values cannot be retrieved until they have
>   been fetched like so:

```
PFObject *post = [fetchedComment objectForKey:@"parent"];
[post fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
  NSString *title = [post objectForKey:@"title"];
}];
```

Clarification on Fetch vs Find: 
Fetches are called on PFObjects ([docs](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html)) whereas Finds are used in PFQueries ([docs](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html)).

Fetches require PFObjects as input, and don't return anything. Fetches simply update the values on PFObjects you've already retrieved from Parse. Finds, on the other hand, will retrieve PFObjects from Parse.

Since you have an array of Powers (which are PFObjects), use the following to retrieve all the values from Parse:

```
[PFObject fetchAllIfNeeded:(NSArray *)myPowers];
```

or `fetchAllIfNeededInBackground:` if you want it to be asynchronous.

Comment: So I'm trying to figure out when to fetch and when to query/find. I assume I can use the code I have (query for all games) and then dig into the data and fetch in the success block?  Just not sure of how to structure this, will try later.

Comment: I've updated the answer with some finer points about fetch vs find!

Comment: Yeah sorry I knew which object the methods are on but your answer does help. I suspected as much. Will give a try later.

Comment: added a simple way for you to retrieve the values of your Powers. let me know how it goes!

Comment: hmm, the `[PFObject fetchAllIfNeeded:(NSArray *)` is crashing on me because i have one PFObject in the Array that is of a different class from the others.  Thanks a lot, i'll get it working now easily, just need to either go down one more level or change structure of the model.

Answer (score 0):

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Cars"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *comments, NSError    *error) {
    for (PFObject *comment in comments)
    {
        PFObject *post = [comment objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSLog(@"%@",post);
```

Comment: You could at least try to complete a whole code snippet with some formatting and explain why you suggest this.